# jPOS installation using linux

Tags: linux, jpos

I want to install a jPOS inside my pc.
I installed jPOS-master.zip file in my pc.

When I want to install the jar file from wrapper folder i write like this:

```
$ java -jar gradle-wrapper.jar
```

But it shows this error

```
no main manifest attribute, in gradle-wrapper.jar
```

What is the errors? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information in the Gradle website, you need to run a 'gradlew' unix script or 'gradlew.bat' if you're on Windows. You can find additional info here:

http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you still in development phase, I suggest you to use compiled jpos. You may find it here: http://jpos.org/maven/
Don't bother compiling jpos unless you are using it in a machine-specific environment, such as IBM AS/400, or other mainframe-like server.